# DRF FormData. Passing arguments in querydict as list of one element

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

#### Front

I **request** to the server with something like:

```json
{
    "name": "myname"
}
```

#### Back

in `request.data`

```py
<QueryDict>: {"name": ["myname"]}
```

**And I had to set this**

```py
for param, val in params.items():
    val = val[0]
```

for every dict item.

**What should I do for getting the correct data**?

Comment: In your front-end, try to set the content type to `application/json`. This behavior suggests that the backend is detecting it as form data.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a problem with the serializer for this object. Make sure that you are not passing a `many=True` argument for the `name` attribute in the serializer.

Check out the last example in this [section](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects). The argument returns the attribute as a list instead of a single object.

Comment: class AuthDataSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AuthData
        fields = ('login', 'password', 'project', 'manager')
login, password, project - string, but in request. data - list